# RxJava Subscribe not working

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following code -

```
package com.test.rxjava;

import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;

public class App1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Subscriber<Integer> subscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer t) {
                System.out.printf("Entry %d\n", t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.err.printf("Failed to process: %s\n", t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Done");
            }

        };
        Flowable.just(123).subscribe(subscriber);

    }

}
```

I was expecting to execute the code in the onNext method.However nothing happens.However If I replace the last line with the below code, I do get the output.

```
Flowable.just(123).subscribe((t) -> System.out.println(t));
```

I am not sure what is missing here. But something definitely is. I am new to Rx world and could use some help to figure out what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `s.request(1)` in `onSubscribe`

Comment: Sorry @DeanXu , I did not understand what you tried to convey.

Comment: see  clemp6r's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subscribers must request items. Add `s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);` in the onSubscribe method, as following:

```
@Override
public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

[See sample code and documentation here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber)